# rxjs execute tap only at the first time

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I want to execute tap() only when i get the first emitted value

Something like:

```
Observable
  .pipe(
     tap(() => { /* execute only when I get the first emitted value */ })
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
     // .....
  })
```

Comment: there is .first() operator among others, you can use it inside .pipe()

Comment: See https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/operators/initial.ts and its dual https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/operators/subsequent.ts

Comment: `stream$.pipe(first() /* sameas take(1)*/, tap(...)).subscribe(() => {})`

Comment: `first` and `take` will auto-subscribe the subscription after one emit

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the index in map operators like `concatMap`. Unlike other approaches this is totally flexible about the chosen index. Let's say if you want tap on 2nd emission `index === 1` or any predicate like `index % 2 === 0`

```js
// these are because of using rxjs from CDN in code snippet, ignore them
const {of, interval} = rxjs;
const {take, tap, concatMap} = rxjs.operators;


// main code
const stream = interval(250).pipe(take(4))

stream.pipe(
  concatMap((value, index) => index === 0
    ? of(value).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('tap'))
      )
    : of(value)
  )
)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.x/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 18):

If I correctly get your idea you want to execute `tap()` only at the beginning of the stream subscription and not other times. **This is my custom operator for that:**

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export function startWithTap<T>(callback: () => void) {
  return (source: Observable<T>) =>
    of({}).pipe(tap(callback), switchMap((o) => source));
}
```

---

**As for example for usage of this operator would be:**

```
this.api.getData().pipe(
  startWithTap(() => this.loading.start()),
)
```

> This is my actual code example where loading gets started when someone
> subscribes to the Observable created by api service (by means of httpClient).

---

**UPDATE**

Use this instead of the above implementation, because this one only uses `defer`, instead of using `of`, `tap` and `switchMap`:

```
export function startWithTap<T>(callback: () => void) {
  return (source: Observable<T>) =>
    defer(() => {
      callback();
      return source;
    });
}
```

Comment: Why the updated solution is better?

Comment: @enno.void updated solution works the same way with only using 1 rxjs operator instead of 3, hence less complication

Comment: This solution is actually behaving differently than the OP asked. It is calling the callback when there is a subscription. It does not call it on the first emission.

Comment: that's actually true, but some people want this behavior and actually end up on this SO question.

Comment: Adding a gotcha here: Neither of these solutions allow the original observable to be delayed. However, jBuchholz's answer does, so I'd recommend going with that if delaying is something you need.

Answer (score 8):

I like the approach of [jal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54099567/7381844) and would suggest wrapping it in its own operator:

```
export function tapOnce<T>(tapFn: (t: T) => void, tapIndex = 0): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
  return source$ => source$.pipe(concatMap((value, index) => {
    if (index === tapIndex) {
      tapFn(value);
    }
    return of(value);
  }));
}
```

Usage would look like this:

```
stream.pipe(tapOnce(() => console.log('tapping once'), 1));
```

This could even be abstracted further to an operator that takes a function to determine whether it should tap according to the given value/index:

```
export function tapWhen<T>(tapFn: (t: T) => void, evaluateFn: (index: number, t: T) => boolean): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
  return source$ => source$.pipe(concatMap((value, index) => {
    if (evaluateFn(index, value)) {
      tapFn(value);
    }
    return of(value);
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If someone interested, here is an **extra simple** implementation of **tapN**. So it executes the specified callback function for each emission until the number of emissions is equal to nEmissions. In order to execute the tap() function only for the first element you would do **tapN(1)**, but you could also execute tap for the 3 firsts emission with tapN(3) for example.

```
/* Executes the specified callback function for each emission until the number of emissions is equal to nEmissions*/
export const tapN = <T>(nEmissions, callback: (T) => void) => (source$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> =>
    defer(() => {
        let counter = 0;
        return source$.pipe(tap((item) => {
            if (counter < nEmissions) {
                callback(item);
                counter++;
            }
        }));
    });
```

In your code:

```
Observable
  .pipe(
     tapN(1, () => { /* this code would be only executed on the first emitted value */ })
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
     // .....
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the already mentioned options you also use `multicast`.

```
multicast(new Subject(), s => concat(
  s.pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(v => console.log('tap', v)),
  ),
  s
)
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-shvuxm

Comment: You have to provide a subject factory function `() => new Subject()` for this to work properly. Providing just one Subject will mess up the values the observable emits if you subscribe multiple times, see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pul1gw?file=index.ts.

Answer (score 0):

You can share() your main Observable like below:

```
import { timer, of, BehaviorSubject, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, mapTo, share, shareReplay, } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source$ = timer(1000)
.pipe(
  tap((v) => console.log('SIDE EFFECT')),
  mapTo('RESULT')
)
const sharedSource$ = source$.pipe(share());
// or shareReplay(1) if you want to ensure every subscriber get the last value event if they will subscribe later;

sharedSource$.subscribe(console.log);
sharedSource$.subscribe(console.log);
sharedSource$.subscribe(console.log);
sharedSource$.subscribe(console.log);
sharedSource$.subscribe(console.log);
sharedSource$.subscribe(console.log);
sharedSource$.subscribe(console.log);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qpnbkm?embed=1&file=index.ts

This is an example like in [learn-rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share)

Answer (score -1):

(Updating my earlier incorrect answer)

Based on cartant's comment and link provided, he has already done the work to create an operator that does this, it is in the 'rxjs-etc' package.  A solution based on his operator is to install 'rxjs-etc', then:

```
import { initial } from 'rxjs-etc/operators';

observable$.pipe(
    initial(src$ => src$.pipe(tap(() => {/* execute only on first value */})))
).
subscribe(() => {
    // ..... 
})
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-54099238?file=index.ts) example.