# How to improve RxJS code to apply a function only for the first emission

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have observable that emitting values every N seconds and I have.
I want to take the first emission and fire a function on that.

I have this code:

```
      sideEffect = false;
      observable$
      .pipe(
        tap((data) => {
          // executing this only for the first emission
          if (!sideEffect) {
            this.sideEffect(data.props);
            sideEffect = true;
          }
        })
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        // process all upcoming emissions
      });
```

Is there anyway to make this code better using RxJS operators without defining any local variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rxjs execute tap only at the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099238/rxjs-execute-tap-only-at-the-first-time)

Answer (score 4):

I would proceed creating 2 separate Observables and then merge them, so that we can have a single subscription. I think this is the most idiomatic way of implementing this logic via **rxjs**.

The code would look something like this

```
const firstEmission$ = observable$
      .pipe(
        take(1),  // you can use also the first() operator which is the same as take(1)
        tap((data) => this.sideEffect(data.props))
      );
const otherEmissions$ = observable$
      .pipe(
        skip(1),
      );
merge(firstEmission$, otherEmissions$).subscribe((data) => {
        // process all upcoming emissions
      });
```

Comment: question: why do you need to `merge` them? and why do you need to `skip(1)` in `otherEmissions$`? - oh is it because the first one is coming from the `firstEmission$` and so you just `merge` to `process them all` use-case, right?

Comment: oh, BTW may be you may have any ideas on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566051/how-to-make-observable-to-repeat

Comment: @sreginogemoh `merge` is used to create a single observable, merging the 2 ones we created, and so have a single subscription. If you so not merge them, you need to subscribe to them separately. `skip(1) is required to avoid that the merged Observable emits twice the first item emitted by `observable$`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `scan` operator that can solve your problem:

```
const stream$ = from([1,2,3,4]).pipe(
  scan((firstValue, value) => {
    if (!firstValue) {
      firstValue = value;
      console.log('performing side effects for value: ', value);
    }
    return value;
  }, null),
  map(value => { /* your further logic here */ return value; })
);
```

`scan` is called for every emission and stores the value inside itself. It's similar to `reduce` function in arrays.
Also be aware that "falsy" values might behave incorrectly (because of `!firstValue` check)